# sklearn MultinomialNB bad input shape in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am new to [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) and encountering an issue when fitting `x_train` and `y_train`. Here is the code with an error

```
def naive_bayes(x_train, y_train):
    clf = MultinomialNB()
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
    joblib.dump(clf, '%s/NB/naive_bayes.pkl' %model_direc)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    train_df = pd.read_json('%s/train.json' %data_direc, orient='index')
    y_train = train_df[['*', '**', '***']].astype(np.float64)

    x_train = pd.read_json('%s/features.json' %feature_direc, orient='columns')
    x_train = x_train.sort_index()

    print x_train.shape
    print y_train.shape

    naive_bayes(x_train, y_train)
```

And here is the output.

```
(80, 1500)
(80, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/NBtrain.py", line 50, in <module>
    naive_bayes(x_train, y_train)
  File "src/NBtrain.py", line 37, in naive_bayes
    clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 474, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, 'csr')
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 444, in check_X_y
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 480, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (80, 3)
```

`features.json` is created using `tf-idf`.

The size of `x_train` is (80, 1500).
The size of `y_train` is (80, 3).

I am not sure why the `y_train` is in a bad shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target value for the `MultinomialNB` should have only one column. In general for classification tasks we only have one target, so if you have more than one distinct target then you will need multiple classifiers.